# Is there a .onReappear equivalent in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this view that has a simple VStack that contains 4 IF conditions, each condition will show the right view:

```
VStack{
        if(showLogin){
            LoginView()
        }
        if(showMain){
            Main()
        }
        if(showSplash){
            Text("Splash screen")
        }
        if(showNoInternet){
            noInternetView(showNoInternet: $showNoInternet, showSplash: $showSplash)
        }
    }
```

For this view I have a `.onAppear()` to run code when this view appears:

```
@State var showLogin = false
@State var showMain = false
@State var showNoInternet = false
@State var showSplash = true

var body: some View {

VStack{
        if(showLogin){
            LoginView()
        }
        if(showMain){
            Main()
        }
        if(showSplash){
            Text("Splash screen")
        }
        if(showNoInternet){
            noInternetView(showNoInternet: $showNoInternet, showSplash: $showSplash)
        }
    }
    .onAppear(){ ... }
}
```

Within the code of `.onAppear()` I check if the user has internet connection, if they don't then I toggle both the `splash` and the `showNoInternetView` to hide the splash screen and show the No Internet connection message. When the user presses a button in the `showNoInternetView`, it does the opposite to hide the message and show the splash screen again, which I would like to run the same code again within the `.onAppear()`. Obviously I know to re-render a view you'd have to change a state - which is what I do to update the views.

How would I invoke the `.onAppear()` function again each time I go back to the original splash view (as if it's the first time the view is being run)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach it instead to splash view directly, so once you come into condition of splash view it will run as expected.

```
    if(showSplash){
        Text("Splash screen")
           .onAppear(){ ... }        // << move here !!
    }
```

Comment: Is that the best way to perform that action as my environment object and called functions cannot be found when I do that - which I tried

Comment: It doesn't get re-run when it goes back either.

Comment: Does `showSplash` switched on this? I don't see all your workflow.

Comment: If showSplash is not toggled, then try to add `.id` as in `.onAppear(){ ... }.id(UUID())`